# App not opening from terminal after installation

Tags: command-line, 14.04, software-center

I'm trying to install Leksah IDE. I followed the instructions on the leksah website and it said it installed correctly, but now it won't *open*.

After installing, I entered:

```
jase@Jase-PC:~$ leksah
Using default Yi configuration
leksah: symbol lookup error: leksah: undefined symbol: gtk_source_language_manager_guess_language
jase@Jase-PC:~$
```

And I got the above error.

I then uninstalled Lekash and installed it again but this time from the Ubuntu Software Ctr. It installed again, but I still get the same error when I try to run it from the terminal. (There appears to be no way to open the IDE from the launcher/dash).

How do I open this thing?

Comment: It seems as if some library is not installed in you system (possibly due to missing dependency). Run `ldd \`which leksah\`` and paste the output.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur Is `sudo apt-get build-dep leksah` the correct way to correct this missing dependency?

Comment: try reinstalling it using sudo apt-get install leksah

Comment: see the bug on this site http://leksah.org/download.html

Comment: @Creator I've already tried that about 3 times since posting this question. No luck. I just ran `sudo apt-get build-dep leksah` and it then downloaded 114MB of stuff. I then re-ran `sudo apt-get install leksah` again and when I try to open leksah I still get the same error. Edit: Just saw your last comment, I'm checking out the link now.

Comment: @Aeron Did you installed leksah from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur Eh, I'm not sure (I'm new-ish to Linux). I installed it using sudo apt-get install leksah in the terminal and when it failed to open after installation i then uninstalled and then installed it via ubuntu software center

Comment: I'm still waiting for `cabal leksah install` to complete. I'll be back with results once it's done.

Comment: Ok, so after running `cabal leksah install`, It seemed to be going OK until right at the end: ghcjs-dom-0.0.10 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
gio-0.12.5.3 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
glib-0.12.5.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
gtksourceview3-0.12.5.0 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
leksah-0.13.4.3 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install.
leksah-server-0.13.1.1 depends on glib-0.12.5.4 which failed to install. I tried installing those, but none of them can be "found". Not sure what to do now